# How we can make the own application of Facebook and yelp in android

Tags: android, facebook, api, yelp

Can any body tell me How we can make the own application of Facebook and Yelp using the API of these application on Android?

Please give me some link and tips for develop it.

Thanx in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

describe you question..what you want to do?? both are provide the API and you can access it and do that as you needed and both provide Developer Help you can use that .

[Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

[Yelp Developer](http://www.yelp.com/developers/)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/